# Download multiple files from Google Cloud Storage (using node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, download, google-cloud-storage

I am using a node.js webserver (NOT hosted in Google Cloud) with Google Cloud Storage to store the files my users upload. Everything is working fine so far but I could not figure out how to allow the users to download their files to their computer. It is simple for single files but for multiple files or folders I would like to create a zip file for download by the user.

Is there any possibility besides downloading the files to my node.js-webserver (not hosted in Google Cloud), create a zip on the webserver and afterwards provide it for download? Which is not working for large files/large amounts of files.
Providing multiple google cloud storage files for download via a webpage doesn't seem to be very exotic...? What did I overlook?

Answer (score -2):

From command line:

```
gsutil -m cp -R gs://<bucket_name>/folder/filematch* /localfolder
```